# Javascript: Divs not recognized?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table, getelementsbytagname

I've been playing around with Javascript to modify the background and theme of my page, http://www.gfcf14greendream.com/, so that it displays a different background in each season, and that works. Now since everything was green before (I am such a freak), I've been experimenting to change the font color of div tags to a readable color depending on the background (for now I'm using a purple on the summer background, `rgb(128, 0, 128)` but if anyone thinks there is a better color let me know), and it has worked, using these lines:

```
var divs = window.parent.document.getElementsByTagName('div');
for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
    divs[i].style.color = "rgb(128, 0, 128)";
}
```

It does work, for these pages that I changed (I haven't changed all since I'm still testing) http://www.gfcf14greendream.com/smssender.html , http://www.gfcf14greendream.com/employmentassistant.html . But while it seems like it works for this page, http://www.gfcf14greendream.com/programs.html , the divs that are inside the table are unaffected (like this div:)

```
<td align="center">
    <div style="text-align: center; color:#00FF00; font-size: 15px">
        <font color="#00FF00">December 16th, 2012</font>
    </div>
</td>
```

So why is it the divs within a `<table>` tag are not recognized? Should I deem tables as obsolete (someone told me they're evil) and try to format one with divs using CSS?

Comment: Don't use javascript, do that with just CSS. Add a season class to the body, and a !important rule to .season div.

Comment: @bfavaretto better yet, get rid of inline styles and `<font ...>`

Comment: The divs style is over ridden by the font tag. Also, tables are not evil just misunderstood. The font tag however *is* evil, and using `!important` is wrong in most cases.

Comment: @Jan: I have to use a single color from now on (unless I use notes like in here http://www.gfcf14greendream.com/tutorials/javatutorials/javastructure.html , or two colors, another one for important words. But that would be it, I would have no need for css font styling or `<font>` tags

Comment: @bfavaretto: I never did this with CSS, frankly I'm expanding my meager knowledge of both languages right now >.< How do you do that?

Comment: @gfcf14 CSS is easy. Just point to a file with contents like `p.main em{color: red; font-weight: bold}` (this particular rule will highlight all `em`phasises inside any `p`aragraph with the class `main`.

Comment: on a side note, please consider a major redesign. The color scheme is pretty agressive IMO and an image banner changing this fast doesn't feel good either.

Comment: Please add `pointer:cursor` to those expandable sections. Clickable elements should indicate they're clickable somehow.

Comment: Ew. Right now, the workflow to read a tutorial is: expand a section, navigate to a subsection, read it, navigate back to the tutorial main page, _expand the same section again_ (or navigate a hover menu, which is impossible on a touch screen), click another link...

Comment: on http://www.gfcf14greendream.com/tutorials/html5tutorials/html5structure.html when viewed on a 1024*x screen, the content bleeds under the menu, and the Saving section bleeds outside the (perceived) content container by a wide amount. Also, what are those green rounded boxes floating on the sides? They seem to be horizontal scrollbars for the left and right columns. Ew.

Comment: `browser-radius` is now supported by Chrome (for a long time, AFAICT). No need to add the prefixed version.

Comment: "[[in the left column]]: these are: [[in the right column]] [[a list of tags]] [[end of both columns and a block of one-column text]]". No. Just no. That doesn't flow naturally. That right column (especially given its different styling) looks like a float that pushes against the left column and doesn't follow the end of the left column.

Comment: I was going to review the content of that tutorial but then I took a fast-spinning road sign gif to the face.

Comment: Clicking `[tutorials][html]` takes you to the directory page and clicking `[tutorials][html][before anything][history]` takes you to a specific section, but clicking `[tutorials][html][before anything]` does not do anything at all.

Comment: Pro-tip: black on mostly black is _really_ hard to read, and I don't want to change my scrolling habits either.

Comment: thanks for all the tips to correct my site! I'll address those issues as soon as I can but I have actually been busy this summer. I haven't changed backgrounds for all my pages (hence http://www.gfcf14greendream.com/tutorials/html5tutorials/html5structure.html is too green yet), but I'll get to it. And then I'm planning on resizing pictures according to window size

Answer (score 2, accepted):

at the moment this isn't working because of the `<font>` tag. The divs style is being affected, however the font tag within is not allowing you to see the changes. Remove the font tag and you should see something.

With that said, you shouldn't be using the `<font>` tag at all. [W3](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/font) tells us HTML5 classifies it as a non-conforming feature, and "... really, don't use it."

Comment: ok I'll look into this tomorrow, since I get this same advice several times. Thank you all for your input! I'll let you know how it goes on

Answer (score 1):

That's because these divs have 'style' attributes, and they override properties you assign with JS. However, it's better to use CSS instead of such magic, just as @bfavaretto said :)

**upd**. I wasn't correct at all, thing is **font** tags have 'style' attributes, and these override property you assign to their parent, **div**.

Comment: If you set some element's `style` from javascript, you are modifying... well... its `style` attribute.

Comment: you know, I haven't tried this yet but it seems like a good advice. I wonder why whoever gave you a -1 didn't bother to explain where your code might fail o_O

Comment: @gfcf14 two different people downvoted, and two different people gave an explanation. The advice is sound, but the explanation is wrong.

Comment: I gave the -1 because this is wrong. Altering the style property does alter the style in the DOM.

Comment: I get that it does, but then which one is called last? Would it be that the js file changes the style but then the inline style overrides whatever was modified?

Comment: no the inline style is parsed first with the html, then the js gets a hold and changes it. check in your DOM inspector (if you have a browser with one).

Comment: @gfcf14 javascript overwrites the style attribute. There is no more an inline style to overwrite what Javascript had done.

Comment: oh yes, I was wrong. Thing is, you have color rgb(128,0,128) assigned to **div** element, while the **font** element has style attribute with green (#0f0) color!

Comment: you all were right. It was the `<font>` tag. I guess when I did it I was too much in a rush to notice I duplicated the font color (which I don't even need now so I'm erasing the inline css as well). Thank you for your help!!

Answer (score 1):

You should really avoid the font tags, as Jan Dvorak pointed out. But even with them, it can be solved with just CSS:

```
div, div font {
    color: rgb(128, 0, 128) !important;
}
```

I'd also add a season class to the body (as in `<body class="summer">`), so I can create multiple styles according to the season:

```
.summer div, .summer div font { color: rgb(128, 0, 128) !important; }
.winter div, .winter div font { color: rgb(0, 0, 255) !important; }
```

Comment: do you really need `!important` to override styling from `font` `color`?

Comment: No. But I'm assuming the markup is a mess, and just wanted to be sure. That would override anything except an inline !important, or an !important within a higher weight selector.

Answer (score 0):

the color of div is modified, but the text is not,this because your text is actually in "font" tag

I see your pages are referencing jquery, try to use this:

```
$('div,div>font').css('color','rgb(128,0,128)')
```

Comment: Please, don't add jQuery to this.

Comment: @bfavaretto jQuery 1.8.3 is already present (though unused) on the page.

Comment: Ah sorry. This isn't tagged jquery

Comment: It would be better to remove (or at least suggest to remove, or at least mention it should be gone) the `font` element